# Why does DNDEBUG flag affect library size?

Tags: optimization, cmake, g++, compiler-flags

I'm trying to optimize the size of my static library foo.a, and compiled it with the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MINSIZEREL` (adds the `-Os` and `-DNDEBUG` flags).

The resulting library size was 307 K.

Now, if I compile with the `-Os` flag only, the library shrinks (very slightly) to 304 K.

As far as I know, using a `-D` flag creates preprocessor defines. Why would this affect the final size of the library?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `-DNDEBUG` moves the build into a quasi-release state. Code paths and symbols that are present in debug builds are no longer present in release builds. Be careful of `-DNDEBUG` on Linux. Some projects depend on debug builds to function semi-properly. See, for example, [Asserts considered harmful (or GMP spills its sensitive information)](https://seclists.org/bugtraq/2018/Dec/46) on the OS Security mailing list.

Comment: That's unusual. Usually you'd expect a code shrink with -DNDEBUG as the turns asserts into no-ops. Conceivable, a compiler could use asserts to guide probabilities and that could lead to some code shrinkage with asserts on as opposed to off, but I wouldn't normally expect it to surpass the code growth due to the assert code being there. What happens if you provide your own assert.h with `#define assert(X) do{if(!(X))__builtin_unreachable();}while(0)
`?

Comment: Are you sure your lib doesn't have an `#if NDEBUG /*...*/ some code` that should have been  `#if !NDEBUG /*...*/ some code` (or the same with `#ifdef` -> `#ifndef` respectively, or with `#if defined(NDEBUG)` -> `#if !defined(NDEBUG)`))